# Angular2: How can I get the boolean function to return the variable derived from the subscribe function?

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I get the function below to return the this.loggedIn variable?

```
    autho(): boolean{

   this.http.get("http://localhost:1337/session").map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
         data => this.loggedIn = data.authenticated,
         err => console.log(err),
         () => console.log('autho API response ', this.loggedIn)


         )

      return this.loggedIn; // I am getting undefined
  }
```

Comment: Hello, your issue is a bit confused. Can you provide us the component that contains the property and show us your component structure. which on contains the other... WIthout thoses informations we can't help you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the *http* class's member is an instance of the angular2 http service your issue is a basic async problem.

`("http://localhost:1337/session")` returns an observable stream which is an object that provides the ability to bind a callback handling the resolution of your function. This resolution is asynchronous, it means that you can't directly return `loggedIn` like you do cause. At this step, the subscribe callback isn't called yet.

You have many ways to achieve what you wan't but be sure to understand the asynchronous state of your code.
I suggest you to transform your observable into a promise that can be chained and return it.

```
@Injectable()
class FooBar {

    ...

    constructor(private http:Http) {}

    ...

    authO():Promise {
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:1337/session')
        .toPromise()
        .then((response:Response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            return this.loggedIn = data.authenticated;
        });
    }




}

//usage 
@Component({...})
class FooBarComponent {

    constructor(private foobarService:FooBar) {

    }

    auth() {
        this.foobarService.auth0()
            .then((loogedIn) => {
                // do some stuff
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(err);
            });
    }

}
```

You can keep the observable and use the subscribe pattern too, but to my mind, the observable/observer pattern is really usefull when an event can be triggered multiple times. The http process can only triggers the subscribe handler once and can't be chained, so the promises are better in this case.

Be sure to require the `toPromise` operator from rxjs to make the example above working.

Anyway, your main issue is trying to use an observer synchronously and this can't be done currently.